# AddMultplicationEquality() for multiple variables

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, mathematical-optimization, or-tools, cp-sat

I want to use `AddMultiplicationEquality()` for multiple variables and use the result of multiplication. I guess we cannot perform the multiplication of multiple decision variables. I am using CP-SAT solver v9.5.2237. This does not give what I want:

```
product_var = model.NewIntVar(1, 1000, 'product_var')
decision_var = [model.NewIntvar(1, 10, 'name_{i}') for _ in range(4)]

#some processing on 'decision_var' and some values are assigned here based on other constrains
# then I want the product of those assigned values in 'decision_var'

model.AddMultiplicationEquality(product_var, constant, decision_var)
```

I get:

> Invalid model: An int_prod constraint should have exactly 2 terms: int_prod

Then I tried:

```
for i in range(4):
    model.AddMultiplicationEquality(product_var, [product_var, decision_var[i])
```

I got this error after presolve:

> Unsat after presolving constraint #17 (warning, dump might be inconsistent): int_prod...

How to carry out the multiplication and get the product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

currently, only x == y * z is supported. No more than 2 variables in the right hand side.

The unsat means your model is inconsistent. This is another issue.

Comment: Where in the official documentation I can read about such restrictions?

Comment: Nowhere currently, or in the code. Both are bad answers, I know :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
num_variables = 10
model = cp_model.CpModel()

dist = [model.NewIntVar(2, 2, 'dist_var') for _ in range(num_variables)]
temp = [model.NewIntVar(1, 10000000, 'temp_var') for _ in range(num_variables )]


model.AddMultiplicationEquality(temp[0], 1, dist[0])

for i in range(1, num_variables):
    model.AddMultiplicationEquality(temp[i], temp[i-1], dist[i])
```

This gave me answer like:

```
temp var : [4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024]
```